# How to center a fixed-width button horizontally?

Tags: html, css, button, center

I have a button whose width is always 50px. How can I keep it center in the parent div horizontally?

Comment: Do your parent div have any fixed height?

Comment: @SujataChanda No,parent div's width is presented by percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

That should do it . . .

Comment: with `position:relative`?

Comment: It shouldn't need position relative.

Answer (score 3):

Make alignment of parent div `center`.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Btn"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{text-align:center;}
.button{width:100px;}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/MA8pM/)

Comment: what if the button is actually a div?

Comment: for `block` element, `margin:0 auto`

Answer (score 1):

What is positioned relative? The button(/div)?

It doesn't matter if it is a button or a div, just give the div class="button", and then you will get the styles.

When you know the exact width of the button, there is also the possibility to position it absolute, but that includes ripping it out of the normal flow (and that might not be what you want).

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <button style="width:50px;position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-25px;">Btn</button>
</div>
```

Depending on what you are trying to obtain, I think I would go for the display:block;margin:auto;

I have forked Hirals fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LRBvT/